Why is $\pi : \partial I^+(\Sigma) \to S$ continuous and injective ? (proof of Penrose's singularity theorem)
I am working out the details of this proof:
Theorem 6.5 (Penrose) [Pen65] Let $(M, g)$ be a connected globally hyperbolic spacetime with a noncompact Cauchy hypersurface $S$, satisfying the null energy condition. If $S$ contains a trapped surface $\Sigma$, then $(M, g)$ is singular.
Proof Let $t : M \to \mathbb{R}$ be a global time function such that $S = t^{-1}(0)$. The integral curves of $\text{grad} \, t$, being timelike, intersect $S$ exactly once, and $\partial I^+(\Sigma)$ at most once. This defines a continuous injective map $\pi : \partial I^+(\Sigma) \to S$, whose image is open. Indeed, if $q = \pi(p)$, then all points in some neighborhood of $q$ are images of points in $\partial I^+(\Sigma)$, as otherwise there would be a sequence $q_k \in S$ with $q_k \to q$ such that the integral curves of $\text{grad} \, t$ through $q_k$ would not intersect $\partial I^+(\Sigma)$. Letting $r_k$ be the intersections of these curves with the Cauchy hypersurface $t^{-1}(t(r))$, for some $r$.
(...)
This is on section 4.6 of An Introduction to Mathematical Relativity by Natario. https://arxiv.org/pdf/2003.02855
I am stuck at this:
-How do I proof that $\pi$ is continuous and injective?
-And why does   $\partial I^+(\Sigma)$ gets intersected at most once by the integral curves of the gradient? (which are timelike by definition of temporal function) This is required for the map $\pi $ to be well-defined but I can't bring myself to argue why.
I am guessing it may have something to do with the flow and ODE's
